# OpenGL ES2 Android Смена ориентации клавиатуры при фиксированной ориентации Activity

Tags: android, opengl

Пишу графическое приложение, возникла проблема: необходимо менять ориентацию клавиатуры, не изменяя ориентацию активити, т.к. при смене ориентации активити, рендер ведет себя не адекватно. Возможно ли как-то сделать такое, не меняя рендер?
То есть androidOrientation всегда должен быть равен landscape, а клавиатура при этом должна всплывать, например, сверху или снизу, при портретной ориентации.

Comment: можете сделать свою, внутриигровую клавиатуру, и показывать ее откуда хотите

Comment: тоже об этом думал, слишком геморройно получается, хочется найти способ проще.

Comment: можете сделать проще - найти исходники готоовй клавиатуры, и использовать ее

Comment: Порывшись в интернете, пришел к выводу что проще рендер переписать. Можно создать KeyboardView, и его вызывать.